# objectMapping(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound) when I try split my URL on MOYA I take 401 error

Tags: json, swift

```
var baseURL: URL {
    return URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/")!
}

var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .getData(_):
        return "popular?api_key=7b409daf7fa0c68a1b2fcaa516c07eaf&language=en-US&"
    }
}
```

when I split my url I take 401 error

> objectMapping(Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil) ("results").", underlyingError: nil)), Status Code: 401, Data Length: 103)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to decode json. Please [edit] your question and add any relevant code as a [example]. See also [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.